# How to replace a transaction web3.py?

Tags: python, blockchain, ethereum, web3py

I want to increase the gas, thereby withdrawing coins from my wallet faster than a hacker. My transaction is created, but not always sent to the network. I attach a small part of the code that is responsible for this function. Periodically, I manage to conduct a transaction, but I need it on an ongoing basis.

```
pending_filter = web3.eth.filter("pending")
deadline = time.monotonic() + 20
while time.monotonic() < deadline:
    pending_txs_hashes = pending_filter.get_new_entries()

    for tx_hash in pending_txs_hashes:
        pending_tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(tx_hash)

        if address_from == pending_tx.get('from') and pending_tx.get('to') != recipient:
            pending_tx = web3.eth.getTransaction(tx_hash)
            print("FOUND: ", (web3.toHex(tx_hash)))
            nonce = pending_tx.get('nonce')
            gas = pending_tx.get('gasPrice')
            recipient = recipient.replace(' ', '')
            
            balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address_from)
            balance = web3.fromWei(balance, 'ether')
            
            x = Decimal(gas * 1.2)/Decimal(1000000000)
            y = x * Decimal(21000)
            
            max_transfer = balance - y / Decimal(1000000000)
            print('gas :', x)
            print('nonce:', nonce)
            # balance = balance - gas*gasPrice-0.002

            if balance > 0:

                tx = {
                    'chainId': chain_id,
                    'nonce': nonce,
                    'to': recipient,
                    'value': web3.toWei(max_transfer, 'ether'),
                    'gas': 21000,
                    'gasPrice': web3.toWei(x, 'gwei'),
                }

                try:
                    balance = web3.eth.getBalance(address_from)
                    print(balance)
                    signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, privat_key)
                    tx_hash = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

Comment: is there a specific reason for why it sometimes isnt sent to the network? what if you try to do it a couple of times if it fails? example:

for i in range(10):
    try:
        ...
    except:
        continue

Comment: @dotheM I've already tried it. It didn't give any results.